# I keep getting [object Object] for my button

Tags: html, reactjs

```
function DragDrop() {
  return (
  <>
   {!isSubmitting ? (
    <FileUploader
      handleChange={handleFileChange}
      name="file"
      //types={fileTypes}
    >
      {!file &&
      <button className="upload-file inter-normal-persian-blue-10-5px">Upload file</button>
      }
      {file &&  (
        <div className="oxygen-normal-tundora-21px">{file_name}</div>
      )}
    </FileUploader>
   ) : (
    // if file is submitting, make this gray area & unclickable
    <div className="frame-213-1-gray"> 
        <div className="oxygen-normal-tundora-21px">{file_name}</div>
    </div>
   )}
  </>
)}
```

I wanted to use this DragDrop function to make upload file button and the upload file button also appear through dropdown menu so I used:

```
function updateUploadFields(id) {
var selectElement = document.getElementById(`mySelect${id}`);
var selectedValue = selectElement.value;

var uploadField1 = document.getElementById(`uploadField1${id}`);
var uploadField2 = document.getElementById(`uploadField2${id}`);
var uploadField3 = document.getElementById(`uploadField3${id}`);

// 초기화
uploadField1.innerHTML = "";
uploadField2.innerHTML = "";
uploadField3.innerHTML = "";

const uploadButton = DragDrop();
if (selectedValue === "Seurat") {
  uploadField1.innerHTML = uploadButton;
} else if (selectedValue === "FastQ") {
  uploadField1.innerHTML = uploadButton;
  uploadField2.innerHTML = uploadButton;
} else if (selectedValue === "Cell Ranger") {
  uploadField1.innerHTML = uploadButton;
  uploadField2.innerHTML = uploadButton;
  uploadField3.innerHTML = uploadButton;
} }
```

but when I choose the dropdown menu, I keep getting [object Object] instead of upload file button. How can I figure out this?

I want to get the upload file button instead of [object Object].

Comment: Perhaps re-edit this to format the code better to enhance clarity

Comment: You can't call React function component directly like `DragDrop()`